# Lista retorna apenas ultimo elemento

Tags: java, array, xml, microsoft-excel, lista

Eae galera, depois de muito trabalho consegui pegar várias tags de um xml para jogar em um relatório Excel. Porém quando populo a lista com meu objeto e passo para o relatório apenas o ultimo elemento é listado. Ja fiz alguns `System.out.println` para mostrar os elementos da lista mas da na mesma, apenas o ultimo elemento aparece. Alguem pode ajudar? Fiz outra lista para testar com o nome de beneficiariosLote e nao tirei ela ainda, com ela eu consigo listar tudo quando faço um FOR, porém não sei como passar uma lista que não tem vinculo com um objeto para o Excel. Obrigado

---

RESUMO:

Quero pegar os dados da lista e preencher um Objeto chamado UnimedLote;
minha `listaLote` retorna o ultimo elemento todo repedido, ou seja, acho que os valores da minha lista estão sendo substituidos a cada iteração do FOR que pega os dados das tags no xml. Quando faço um debug line com SysOut pegando o Objeto contato ele lista normal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando eu tento exibir a lista é isso que aparece: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa imagem mostra apenas um trecho pois a lista é extensa, porém o mesmo cliente é repetido por toda a lista.

```
public List<UnimedLote> realizaLeituraXML(String arquivoXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    //fazer o parse do arquivo e criar o documento XML
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(arquivoXML);

    Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList tagdadosLote = elem.getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosLote");
    List<UnimedLote> listaLote = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.printf("\n tagdadosLote %s ", tagdadosLote.getLength());
    UnimedLote contato = new UnimedLote();
    for (int i = 0; i < tagdadosLote.getLength(); i++) {
        String lote = "";

        Element elementoLote = (Element) tagdadosLote.item(i);
        lote = pegaTag(elementoLote, "unimed:numeroLote");
        contato.setNumLote(lote);

        NodeList tagGuia = (NodeList) elementoLote.getElementsByTagName("unimed:guia");
        // Como sabemos pela estrutura que só tem 1 elemento não necessitamos de um for podendo fixar o indice.
        NodeList tagdadosGuia = ((Element) tagGuia.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosGuia");
        System.err.println("LOTE: " + lote);
        for (int y = 0; y < tagdadosGuia.getLength(); y++) {
            NodeList tagProcedimentos = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimentos");
            NodeList tagBeneficiario0 = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:beneficiario");
            NodeList tagProcedimentos1 = ((Element) tagProcedimentos.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosProcedimento");
            NodeList tagProcedimento = ((Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimento");
            /*Beneficiarios*/
            Element elementoBeneficiario0 = (Element) tagBeneficiario0.item(0);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario0, "unimed:numeroCarteira"));
            contato.setCodigo(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario0, "unimed:numeroCarteira"));

            Element elementoBeneficiario = (Element) tagBeneficiario0.item(0);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario, "unimed:nomeBeneficiario"));
            contato.setNomeBeneficiario(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario, "unimed:nomeBeneficiario"));
            /*Beneficiarios*/

            /*Dados das Guias*/
            Element elementoBeneficiario1 = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario1, "unimed:numeroGuiaOperadora"));
            contato.setNumeroDocumento(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario1, "unimed:numeroGuiaOperadora"));

            Element elementoBeneficiario2 = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario2, "unimed:valorProcessadoGuia"));
            Element elementoBeneficiario3 = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario3, "unimed:valorLiberadoGuia"));
            /*Dados das Guias*/

            /*Procedimentos*/
            Element elementoBeneficiario4 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(0);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario4, "unimed:valorProcessado"));
            Element elementoBeneficiario5 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(0);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario5, "unimed:dataProcedimento"));
            contato.setData(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario5, "unimed:dataProcedimento"));

            //Procedimento(tag que fica dentro de procedimentos)!!
            Element elementoBeneficiario6 = (Element) tagProcedimento.item(0);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario6, "unimed:codigo"));
            contato.setProcedimento(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario6, "unimed:codigo"));

            Element elementoBeneficiario7 = (Element) tagProcedimento.item(0);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario7, "unimed:descricao"));
            contato.setDescricaoProced(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario7, "unimed:descricao"));
            //Procedimento(tag que fica dentro de procedimentos)!!

            Element elementoBeneficiario8 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(0);
            beneficiariosLote.add(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario8, "unimed:quantidadeExecutada"));
            contato.setQtdExecutada(pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario8, "unimed:quantidadeExecutada"));

            Element elementoBeneficiario9 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(0);

            String filme = pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario9, "unimed:valorFilme");
            if (filme
                    == null) {
                filme = "0";
            }
            BigDecimal vp = new BigDecimal(filme).setScale(2);
            contato.setCustoFilme(vp);
            beneficiariosLote.add(vp);

            Element elementoBeneficiario10 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(0);
            String custo = pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario10, "unimed:valorServico");
            if (custo
                    == null) {
                custo = "0";
            }
            BigDecimal vc = new BigDecimal(custo).setScale(2);
            contato.setCustoServico(vc);
            beneficiariosLote.add(vc);

            Element elementoBeneficiario11 = (Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(0);

            String hon = pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario11, "unimed:valorHonorario");
            if (hon
                    == null) {
                hon = "0";
            }
            BigDecimal vh = new BigDecimal(hon).setScale(2);
            contato.setHonorario(vh);
            beneficiariosLote.add(vh);
            //Dados Guias
            Element elementoBeneficiario12 = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);

            String tot = pegaTag(elementoBeneficiario12, "unimed:valorInformado");
            if (tot
                    == null) {
                tot = "0";
            }
            BigDecimal vt = new BigDecimal(tot).setScale(2);
            contato.setValorTotalInformado(vt);
            beneficiariosLote.add(vt);
            /*Dados das Guias*/
            System.err.println("Contatos: " + contato);    
            listaLote.add(y,contato);

        }

    }

    System.err.println("Lista lote: "+listaLote);
    return listaLote;

}
```

Trecho aonde preencho as colunas no Excel:
 //Percorre a lista e preenche as celulas

```
        int cont2=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaContatoslt.size(); i++) {


            XSSFRow cabRowAnalitico7 = sheet1.createRow(i + 6);
            for (int x = 0; x <= 12; x++) {
                cabRowAnalitico7.createCell(x);
            }

            XSSFCell cellAnaA5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(0);
            cellAnaA5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
            cellAnaA5.setCellValue(listaContatoslt.get(i).getNumeroDocumento());

            XSSFCell cellAnaB5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(1);
            cellAnaB5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
            cellAnaB5.setCellValue(listaContatoslt.get(i).getCodigo());

            XSSFCell cellAnaC5 = cabRowAnalitico7.getCell(2);
            cellAnaC5.setCellStyle(estiloS2);
            cellAnaC5.setCellValue(listaContatoslt.get(i).getNomeBeneficiario());
            cont2++;
            }
```

Comment: Qual objeto?, qual parte, especifica  limitando ao máximo, ou seria preciso muito tempo para tentar ajudar você

Comment: Editei a pergunta, não sei se ficou melhor mas está difícil até pra explicar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está em você criar um único objeto do tipo `UnimedLote` antes do for

Esta linha

```
UnimedLote contato = new UnimedLote();
```

Deve ficar dentro do seu `for`.

Comment: Poxa viajei legal, muito obrigado por me ajudar.